# Error message id: cannot find name for group ID after logging in

Tags: login, group, etc

**BACKGROUND**

Trevor logs into his account on ssh://foobar.university.edu as one of the developers on the box, and he gets the message:

```
 id: cannot find name for group ID 131
```

Trevor then checks this out using

```
 vim /etc/group
```

**PROBLEM**

Trevor discovers that there *is* no 131 anywhere in the /etc/group file.

Trevor then runs id ...

```
 > id trevor
 uid=4460(trevor) gid=131 groups=48(foobar),51(doobar),131
```

To discover his primary group apparently does not have a name attached to it.

**QUESTIONS**

- What likely happened to cause this circumstance on the foobar.university.edu box ?
- Suppose trevor wants to fix this (e.g., by just creating a "trevor" group that maps to GID 131) what is the best way to do this without potentially breaking anything else on the server ?

Comment: Or maybe you have an incorrectaccess right on /etc/group file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What likely happened is that the UID and GID are provided to the server via LDAP.  If the `/etc/group` file doesn't contain the translation for the GID, then the server administrators likely just failed to update the group definitions.  What can you do?  Not much.  The user id is controlled by the administrator. (Now if you happen to have ROOT privileges, you can add the group into `/etc/group`.  You should also check to see if any other user accounts are using the same group, and if they are, name the group appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Additional note: If you do have sufficient privileges; adding to group file can be done via

     `groupadd --gid 131 foobargroup`

Comment: @dreftymac Assuming that running `id` reports the same ID for uid, gid and groups, I guess it is safe to `groupadd -gID username`?

Comment: If this account was configured using an sssd with ldap/ad, another possibility(if you have root access on your system) is that your ldap_group_search_base attribute isn't general enough, and doesn't contain the group your system is searching for.

Comment: what does it mean "file doesn't contain the translation for the GID"? can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Gulzar What I mean by "translation here" is that when looking up the GID in `/etc/group` if there isn't a key with the GID, then it can't tell you who is in the group.

Answer (score 5):

This happened when my user "jackson" wasn't assigned a group. I knew the solo group id for my user was 1000 (when a user is created with `$ adduser` and no parameters are defined, the user is assigned the next ids available beyond 999. The first getting uid 1000 and gid 1000).

This warning means your user does not belong to a group so what you need to do is to add the user to a group. Either have your admin help you like @sparticvs mentioned or if you have root privileges / it's your machine you can do the following:

```
$ addgroup [your_user_name]
$ usermod -a -G [your_user_name] [your_user_name]
```

And that should fix it (*untested*)

What I did was simply **(advanced)**

- `$ sudo vi /etc/group`
- modify the line of `web:x:1001:` to `web:x:1000:jackson`

Which made my user `jackson` belong to the `web` group.

*FYI if you're not familiar with `vim` I do not recommend the "advanced" steps, if you're really really desperate use `$ sudo nano /etc/group`*

Comment: good job on the **advanced** disclaimer ... that could cause some unhappiness and breakage if one were not aware of the implications.

Comment: A better option than using `vi` directly is to use the specialised version, [vigr](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/8/vigr/). It makes a temporary copy and checks the syntax before saving, making it a lot safer when editing such an important. It's available in BSD and GNU/Linux (from the `util-linux` package). Similar tools exist for other important files, e.g., `vipw`, `visudo` .

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you are running a VM that usually gets its data from LDAP, but is unable to connect.  I'm sure that there's a way to fix this, but I usually just reboot it once the connection is available again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue but with ad authentication. How to solve:

```
systemctl stop winbind
systemctl stop smbd.service
net cache flush
rm /var/lib/samba/*.tdb
systemctl start smbd.service
systemctl start winbind.service
```

logon again and problem solved.

How to clear winbind cache: http://raafat.tawasol.net/clear-winbind-cache/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AD to authenticate, could be that in sshd config you do not have enabled parameter `auto_private_groups = true` and after login OS is not able to create private gorup what is neede to chmod /home/user to correct permissions. Check:

```
[domain/YOUR_DOMAIN]
...
# https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/gid-for-ad-users
# virtual private groups
auto_private_groups = true
```

than restart `sssd` and re-login.