# Copying files from Linux Server to Local (Windows)

Tags: linux, file-copy

I had a look into all the threads for resolving my issue before posting it here but unfortunately I couldn't solve it.

I would like to copy the files from my linux Server to my local Windows desktop Folder. Am using Openshift and I want to copy the files from the pods.

```
scp 1000000000@HALXXXXXXX:Testnew.pdf c:/Users/Desktop
```

It Returns me with Unknown user 1000000000

When I try

```
whoami
cannot find Name for user ID 1000000000
```

Any help on this will be much more appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63182/whoami-cannot-find-name-for-user-id-0

Comment: When I try /etc/passwd it Returns me with /etc/passwd: Permission denied

Comment: So, you are trying to SCP using the remote UID in place of the username - which apparently doesn't exist? Perhaps the issue is similar to this: [Error message id: cannot find name for group ID after logging in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/54953/error-message-id-cannot-find-name-for-group-id-after-logging-in)